# Suppose that $f: \mathbb R^q \to \mathbb R^p$ is a linear map. Prove that $f$ is differentiable and that $f'(x) = f$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^q$

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R^q \to \mathbb R^p$ is a linear map. Prove that $f$ is differentiable and that $f'(x) = f$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^q$.

I don't know of any way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ means there exists a linear transformation $T$ such that
\begin{equation}
f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + T(\Delta x) + o(\Delta x)
\end{equation}
as $\| \Delta x \| \to 0$.

In your problem, there does exist such a linear transformation $T$, namely $T = f$.
Indeed,
\begin{equation}
f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + f(\Delta x) + 0.
\end{equation}

Hence $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x) = T$.